# jQuery UI Focus Issue

Tags: jquery-ui

I am getting Issue

> unable to get property'_focusTabbable'of undefined or null reference

I am using Jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js

Here I am getting issue in

```
if ( !$.ui.dialog.overlayInstances ) {
    // Prevent use of anchors and inputs.
    // We use a delay in case the overlay is created from an
    // event that we're going to be cancelling. (#2804)
    this._delay(function() {
        // Handle .dialog().dialog("close") (#4065)
        if ( $.ui.dialog.overlayInstances ) {
            this.document.bind( "focusin.dialog", function( event ) {
                if ( !that._allowInteraction( event ) ) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    **$(".ui-dialog:visible:last .ui-dialog-content")
                        .data( widgetFullName )._focusTabbable();**
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this your code? or is it some plugin? or is it jquery UI itself?

Comment: It is a Jquery Ui Itself

Comment: For anybody in my situation, I ran into this error message a lot when stacking dialogs a couple times in a row while using a custom implementation of jQuery.ui.dialog made with the widget factory. It looks like the issue was patched in jQuery UI master so I made this quick hack until we can update. https://pastebin.com/Q6ChMU84

Answer (score 12):

This bug arises when you open a dialog and then, in an action button of this dialog, call a method that opens a second dialog.  When you attempt to close the second dialog, the bug appears.

To prevent this from happening, close the first dialog immediately, and then call the second dialog.

```
$('#dialog1').dialog({

    buttons: {
        'No': function () {
            $(this).dialog('close')
        },

        'Yes': function () {

            // This works
            $(this).dialog('close');

            // Open second dialog
            OpenSecondDialog()

            // This doesn't work.  A bug will arise when attempting to close the second dialog
            $(this).dialog('close');

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You saved my life! :D

Comment: Yikes! This is a really nasty bug to find since it breaks jquery ui and gives errors in _later_ code, in my case in some other, unrelated code. This should be seen as a bug in the jquery dialog code.

Comment: This was fixed by https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/pull/1817/commits/9c3ea5b0d838b657dbc5c692ceb723ea37c1126d on 2017-05-17, but the last release as of today is still 1.12.1, 2016-09-14.

Answer (score 1):

I'm opening one dialog and then another to confirm changes which were done in the first dialog. When confirming it doesn't close the first dialog which was opened. So I'm just destroying everything to get rid of the focus issue.

```
$(".ui-dialog-content").dialog('destroy');
```

I just put this one in the confirm function of the last dialog so it destroys all my dialogs (since they have the same class).

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference (and in case anyone else experiences this problem), I got the same error in jQuery UI 1.10.3 when re-opening a dialog after partial postbacks in asp.net. I found out that this was due to a variable `$.ui.dialog.overlayInstances` that is supposed to evaluate to 1 before the dialog is closed. Since every time the dialog is opened the variable is increased by 1, when the user pressed the close button my value often evaluated to 2 or more. My solution was to reset `$.ui.dialog.overlayInstances` to 1 every time I opened the dialog. So:

```
$("#myDiv").dialog("open");
$.ui.dialog.overlayInstances = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working jquery-ui-1.12.1 and encountered the same error and as [Emyr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218506/emyr) pointed out this bug has been fixed.

My first workaround used [George Beiers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5128440/george-beier) approach. Close dialog1 before creating dialog2, then I would restore dialog1 after closing dialog2. The result didn't look so well but it cleared the error in every browser except Internet Explorer.

Turns out there was a function that was attempting to closed my dialog1(already closed) before closing dialog2. Once I reordered the code I was able to keep dialog1 open while I displayed dialog2.

My suggestion if you are having trouble fixing this issue is to add a console log message on the [beforeClose](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-beforeClose) and [open](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open) events to keep an eye for odd behavior.

Answer (score -1):

I remember that error. 
For me was
I tried to open a modal by code, then I opened other modal also by code...
They opened well... but if tried again, I received that error.
I had to close the first modal before open a new one.